# Не получается переустановить Windows на Surface Laptop 1

Tags: windows, ssd

Приобрел устройство уже с проблемой, что пользователь не смог переустановить Windows 10.

Имеется Microsoft Surface Laptop 1:
i7 7660U, 8Gb, 256Gb.

Что я сделал:

1. Скачал iso образ восстановления для своего устройства: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surfacerecoveryimage
2. Создал загрузочную флешку по инструкции в документации, 32Gb, FAT32. Поместил в нее файлы от iso образа с заменой.
3. Вставил в ноутбук и загрузился с нее, вначале попробовал:

   Troubleshoot -> Recover from a drive -> Just remove my files or Fully clean the drive ( получил ошибку ): Error: Reset this pc there was a problem resetting your pc. no changes were mode.

Чуть-чуть по другому попробовал:

Troubleshoot -> Advenced options -> Startup Repair ( получил ошибку ) Error: Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC Press "Advanced options" to try other options to repair your PC or "Shut down to turn off your PC.

4. Решил, что нужно попробовать через cmd.
   Troubleshoot -> Advenced options -> Command Prompt
   X:\windows\system32> diskpart

   Version 10.0.15063.0

Далее все на фотографиях.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал еще так:

```
select disk 0 ( получается выбрать disk 0, хотя в list disk он не отображается ).

list partition
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее стал пробовать снова восстановить методами Windows:
Troubleshoot -> Recover from a drive -> Just remove my files or Fully clean the drive ( но получил уже другую ошибку )

Recover from a drive
Unable to recover your PC. The system drive is too small.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу понять, как восстановить Nvme. Прошу помочь советами :)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, поможет форматирование диска.

Для этого, откройте diskpart, выберите диск и очистите его. **(при этом все данные будут удалены)**

```
>diskpart

DISKPART> list disk
DISKPART> select disk 1
DISKPART> clean all
```

Теперь (в теории) установщик Windows должен найти место на диске. Если не помогло, то попробуйте создать 1 полноразмерный раздел на диске.

Comment: Спасибо за совет :)

Попробовал как вы сказали:
list disk у меня меня отображается только загрузочный диск под как disk 1, а disk 0 ( система в формате raw  не отображается ).

Выполнил следующие команды:
select disk 0

clean all

В ответ получил: DiskPart has encountered an error: Incorrect function. See the System Event Log for more information.

Я гуглил как через diskpart создать полноразмерный раздел, но так и получилось из-за raw.